# Does optimization change the behavior of casts?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc4

I'm working with a small UART device and frequently need to switch the baud rate at which it operates.
Essentially the whole set-up boils down to

```
#define FOSC 2000000
#define BAUD 9600

uint8_t rate = (uint8_t) ((FOSC / (16.0 * BAUD)) - 1 + 0.5);
```

(Where +0.5 is used to round the result.)

I'm currently compiling with gcc 4.8.1, `-O1`.
Does the compiler optimize away the whole cast or am I left with a cast followed by a constant? Would this differ with different `-O#` values (besides `-O0`)? What about `-Os` (which I might have to compile with eventually)?

If it matters, I'm developing for the [Atmel AT90USB647](http://www.atmel.com/devices/AT90USB647.aspx?tab=overview) (or the [datasheet **[pdf]**](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc7593.pdf)).

Comment: Eh? Preprocessing is just string replacement. It doesn't handle anything at the semantic level.

Comment: That is to say: You could ask about `uint8_t rate = (uint8_t) (2000000 / (16.0 * 9600)) - 1 + 0.5` and leave the preprocessor out of it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Pardon if I have mixed up what compilation step does exactly what, I'm not seasoned with C.

Comment: Short answer, though -- this will be made a compile-time constant on gcc4, probably even with `-O0`, but certainly with anything else.

Comment: @user1320881, I'm guessing the OP thinks that the cast operation has a runtime cost?

Comment: could you please specify the platform on which you intend to run the compiled code as well?

Comment: compile with `-S` and have a look at the assembly file `.s`.

Comment: Why are you only casting the `(FOSC / (16.0 * BAUD))` part instead of the whole `(FOSC / (16.0 * BAUD)) - 1 + 0.5`?

Comment: A bit off-topic but worth remembering: The `+ 0.5` trick for rounding produces wrong results if the variable being rounded is negative (not the case in the code you've posted)

Comment: @halex I was mistaken in thinking that additional parentheses aren't needed there, I take it from your comment that they are?

Comment: Do you want to set custom baud rates? if yes this can become very different and complex depending on the OS.

Comment: @Nit You are explicitly casting the part `(FOSC / (16.0 * BAUD))` into type `uint8_t` which will be implicitly casted into type double because you add the double literal `0.5` and finally the whole computed right side is implicitly casted to type `uint8_t` because of C's conversion rules. In fact you can completely get rid of the `(uint8_t)` cast, because according to C standard floating point numbers can be implicitly converted to every integer types if the value fits into its range (see *6.3.1.4  Real floating and integer* in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf).

Comment: have you seen page 179 of [this](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc7593.pdf) document? I don't understand the addition of `0.5` in your equation.

Comment: @Barracuda See halex's comment and the rounding comment.

Comment: @halex Thanks for your comment, I've added the parenthesis for the clarity of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **extremely likely** that any sane compiler will convert that entire expression (including the cast) into a constant when compiling with optimizations enabled.

However, to be sure, you'll need to look at the assembly output of your compiler.

## But what about GCC 4.8.1 in particular?

#### Code

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define FOSC 2000000
#define BAUD 9600

int main() {
    uint8_t rate = (uint8_t) (FOSC / (16.0 * BAUD)) - 1 + 0.5;
    printf("%u", rate);
}
```

#### Portion of the generated assembly with `gcc -O1 red.c`

```
main:
.LFB11:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $12, %esi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
```

We can see clearly that gcc has precomputed the value of `12` for `rate`.

Comment: The question is tagged gcc4, so we can assume that compiler.

Comment: I think the platform and the hardware matters too. It's very likely that OP would want to run this code on an embedded device.

Comment: @Barracuda: The generated assembly may be different, but a constant propagation optimization pass will work on any architecture.

Comment: @BillLynch I used to think the same but I have personally seen that `gcc` optimized uninitialized integer values to their maximum or `0` in the same code and it was supposed to run on ARM processors.

Comment: @Barracuda: The constant that the value is equal to could be different depending on the size of your `int`, `long` and `double`. But that doesn't mean that the compiler doesn't push it to a constant.

Comment: @BillLynch I didn't say it won't push it to a constant. I said it would be more concrete if we could have more info about the target architecture and platform.

Answer (score 0):

Atmel AVR ships [newlib](https://sourceware.org/newlib/) C library which is a simple ANSI C library, math library, and collection of board support packages. You may refer to ANSI C specifications to find out. Specifically the Conversion section.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that rate is being written to a volatile variable or pointer. Maybe the rate value is calculated OK, but when it's written to the peripheral destination it is lacking the volatile tag and the optimizer does not perform the write operation.